# How to change the width of a primeng autocomplete multiple?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to change the width of a primeng auto complete component to fill the column of a table, I already tried to use

```
style="width: 100%"
```

but that doesn't work; I also tried to set this on html but nothing changes

```
[style]="{'width':'100%'}" [inputStyle]="{'width':'100%'}" class="p-autocomplete"
```

Current situation:

[image]

What I'm failing to do:

[image]

primeng version: 9.0.0

link for the the code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablebasic-demo-p9egw5?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to me worked that way, font: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1552

```
 <td>
    <div class="ui-fluid">
        <p-autoComplete 
           styleClass="wid100"
           [(ngModel)]="texts" 
           [suggestions]="results"
           (completeMethod)="search($event)" 
           [multiple]="true">
        </p-autoComplete>
    </div>
 </td>
```

Answer (score 2):

My english is very poor but you can test this

```
<td class="p-fluid">
            <!-- <input type="text" style="width: 100%" /> -->
            <p-autoComplete [(ngModel)]="texts" [suggestions]="results" (completeMethod)="search($event)"
                [multiple]="true">
            </p-autoComplete>
</td>
```

I hope willbe helpful.

Comment: its works on the code snippet but not on my project... maybe some primeng version issue, to work i have to add outher classes as the answer what i will post

Answer (score 0):

Which browser do you use? As of Chrome its looks like expected
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bmEe.png)